# Delphi DBgrid undo change on error update

Tags: delphi, datasource

I have in my code a validation of edited value on the datachange for my datasource :

```
procedure TForm1.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
var
sIDin :string;
Continue                :boolean;
begin
    Continue := True;
    if (Table1.RecordCount <> 0 )and (Field <> Nil) then
    begin
        //////////
        if (Field.Text = '') then //(1)
        begin
             Application.MessageBox('is Empty!','',MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING);
             Continue := false;
        end
        else if (Field.FieldName <> 'GaName') and  (Field.FieldName <> 'MnName' )then
        begin
             sIDin := '$0' + Field.Text;
             if not TryStrToInt64(sIDin) then
             begin
                  Application.MessageBox('Not Hexadecimal!', '',MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING);
                  Continue := false;
                  //Field.Text := ''; // here i need to set  my filed empty not with wrong value. 
                  // So i use this line .. 
                  // but it generate an error (1)
             end;
        end;
        if Not(Continue) then
            abort
    end;
    inherited ;

end;
```

I need to undo change when enter not validate data in this case :

```
if not TryStrToInt64(sIDin) then
begin
      Application.MessageBox('Not Hexadecimal!', '',MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING);
      Continue := false;
end;
```

Example when i enter a not Hexdecimal value ('NONEHexa'), i need to ignore this value from my dataset.
I try to set my field with empty  `Field.Text := ''` but it will generate other error when my field is empty.

How i can do that?

============ Update1

my function TryStrToInt64:

```
    function TryStrToInt64(InputString : string) : boolean ;
    var
    iValue64          :Int64;
    begin
            try
                    iValue64 := StrToInt64(InputString);
            Except
                    on E : EConvertError  do
                    begin
                            Result:= false;
                            exit;
                    end;
            end;
            Result:=true;
    end;
```

Comment: What other error will be generated when your field is empty?  Have you looked at Delphi's HexToBin function?  Also, which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: because i add `Field.Text := ''`,  the other error is generated by `if (Field.Text = '') then
        begin
             Application.MessageBox('is Empty!','',MB_OK + MB_ICONWARNING);
             Continue := false;
        end`... i use Delphi5.. the function TryStrToInt64 is implemented by me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attempting to convert your field value to an integer, you could
test whether each of its characters is valid in a Hex string, with something like this:

```
function ValidHex(Input : String) : Boolean;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  //  If Input is empty, it can't be valid Hex
  if Input = '' then exit;

  //  Valid Hex must have an even number of characters
  if Odd(Length(Input)) then exit;

  for i := 1 to Length(Input) do
    if not (CharInSet(Input[i], ['0'..'9', 'A'..'F', 'a'..'f'])) then
      exit;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Of course, you could use the HexToBin library function to convert a Hex string to a binary value and check whether all the characters in the string are consumed in the process.

Three things about your code:

1. Rather than trying to do your validation in the datasource's `OnDataChange` event, it would be better to do it in the **field**'s `OnValidate` event, which is provided to do exactly this kind of validation.  See the Online Help for details.
2. You can use the field's `EditMask` properties to restrict the characters that can be entered into it   Again, see the OLH.  I don't think you can use EditMask to restrict the input to Hex characters, though.
3. You would do better to avoid the use of `Continue` as a variable.  It has a special meaning to the compiler, to do with the execution of `for` loops.  Again, see the OLH

Update:

> I try, but i can see how to ensure the validation with TField OnValidate.. can you give an example!.. other question : When i use the OnValidate for field, it is possible to UNDO update on some field IF it's false? Example : when i enter a Non hexadecimal value, my field should rollback and not accept this value.. In my case, I can get this error on DataChange event. But before that when i click on other row, the wrong value seem be saved on my database!

The wrong value is saved because when you click on another grid row while there is an unsaved change to the current row, that change is automatically saved - that's standard behaviour for a Delphi dataset.

If you want to revert the field value to what it was before the user's change, it is easiest to use the datasource's OnDataChange event rather than the field's OnValidate.  The call to `Field.DataSet.Cancel` in the following will revert the field's value:

```
procedure TForm1.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
  if Field = Nil then Exit;
  // First, check that the Field is the one we're interested in
  if Field = Field.DataSet.FieldByName('Value') then begin
    if not ValidHex(Field.AsString) then begin
      ShowMessageFmt('Invalid value: %s for field: %s', [Field.AsString, Field.FieldName]);
      Field.DataSet.Cancel;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Be aware, however, that this will revert any other unsaved changes to the same row.  To be able to revert only the change to the "hex" field would be a lot more complicated - I think you'd have to save the other changed values somewhere and reinstate them after the call to `Cancel`.

Comment: my fields are defined dynamically.. in some case,  i have 2 fields .. in other case, i have 4 fields.. I can't defined my field ..

Comment: The fact that your fields are dynamically defined doesn't preclude the use of OnValidate or EditMask - it's just a question of setting these properties in code.

Comment: With Delphi 5, is there a ONValidate or EditMask for fields? .. i try to add some field in FiledDefs propertie for my dataset .. but i can see the OnValidate event for this created field!

Comment: Yes, there are OnValidate and EditMask properties in D5 - see the source in DB.Pas.  But they are properties of TField and its descendants, **not** TFieldDef.

Comment: I try, but i can see how to ensure the validation with TField OnValidate.. can you give an example!.. other question : When i use the OnValidate for field, it is possible to UNDO update on some field IF it's false?   Example : when i enter a Non hexadecimal value, my field should rollback and not accept this value.. In my case, I can get this error on DataChange event. But before that when i click on other row, the wrong value seem be saved on my database!